# Google Drive API con PHP - Problemas en actualizar el token

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Estoy intentando actualizar el token en el código PHP pero no está funcionando. Estoy usando el API de Google Drive con PHP, el código funciona bien en el navegador hasta que el token expira, revisando en otras páginas he cambiado el código de esta forma:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
if (!file_exists("client_id.json")) exit("Client secret file not found");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_id.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

if (file_exists("credentials.json")) {
$access_token = (file_get_contents("credentials.json"));
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
//Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

 $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken(); 
 $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);
 $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();
 $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;
 file_put_contents("credentials.json", json_encode($accessTokenUpdated));

 //También lo he intentado de esta forma pero tampoco funciona:
 //$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
 //file_put_contents("credentials.json", json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}

$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles(); //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975479/call-to-undefined-method-google-service-drive-filelistgetitems
echo json_encode($files_list);
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

**oauth2callback.php**

```
<?php
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_id.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE); //::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY
 if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 } else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
  file_put_contents("credentials.json", json_encode($access_token));

  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

Pero sigo recibiendo el mensaje de error en los logs:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken' in /var/www/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:266\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/drive/index.php(14): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken(NULL)\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/drive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 266

Lo que tengo que hacer es eliminar manualmente el archivo **credentials.json** que almacena el token expirado y generar uno nuevo ejecutando **index.php** y siendo redirigido **oauth2callback.php** cada hora, pero esa no es la idea.

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Me gustaría recibir su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione el refresh token debes especificar el setAccessType() de dejo el bloque de código:

```
<?php
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_id.json');
 $client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/drive/oauth2callback.php');
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE); //::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY


 // offline: Necesario para renovar token de acceso a GDrive
 $client->setAccessType("offline");


 if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 } else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    file_put_contents("credentials.json", json_encode($access_token));

    $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 }
```

?>

NOTA: Te recomiendo eliminar tu archivo client_id y generar uno nuevo antes de generar el token para evitar problemas.

Comment: Este cambio sólo lo tengo que realizar en el oauth2callback.php ?

Comment: Generar un nuevo client_id implicaría tener que borrar y crear una nueva credencial OAuth en el Google Console?

Comment: Si, nada mas ahí, porque es donde se genera el token

Comment: Si es posible, si borrar y crear uno nuevo, al menos a mi, me genero confilcto cuando solo agregue el setAccessType con el mismo client_id.

Comment: Los cambios y ahora funciona genial, gracias!